# Libgdx, actor touchlistener not working

Tags: libgdx, game-design, touch

```
public class Main extends ApplicationAdapter {

SpriteBatch batch;

OrthographicCamera camera;

Stage stage;

Image greyback;
Image circle;

private float width;
private float height;

@Override
public void create () {

    batch = new SpriteBatch();

    camera = new OrthographicCamera();

    stage = new Stage();
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

    greyback = new Image(new Texture("greyback.png"));
    circle = new Image(new Texture("circle.png"));

    width = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    height = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

    greyback.setWidth(width);
    greyback.setHeight(height);

    circle.setPosition(200,200);

    circle.setBounds(200, 200, circle.getWidth(), circle.getHeight());
    circle.setTouchable(Touchable.enabled);
    circle.addListener(new InputListener() {

        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {

            System.out.println("CLICKED");

            return true;

        }

        public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {

            System.out.println("REMOVED");

        }

    });

    stage.addActor(greyback);
    stage.addActor(circle);

}

@Override
public void render () {

    stage.draw();

}
```

}
But, when I click on the circle the touchlistener doesnt fire, why?

Comment: Have you used a breakpoint to make sure it's not firing or are you just looking for the output in the console? If the output then are you on Desktop or android? `System.out.println()` only works on desktop. You can use `Gdx.app.log()` to make sure that it goes to the appropriate output regardless of platform

Comment: im using System.out.println(); on the desktop.

Answer (score 1):

In your call

```
circle.setBounds(200, 200, circle.getWidth(), circle.getHeight());
```

The `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` calls are methods on Actor, not Image. You have not set the Actor's width and height, so you are setting its bounds to a rectangle with a height and width of 0... no clickable area.

Change the call to

```
circle.setBounds(200, 200, circle.getImageWidth(), circle.getImageHeight());
```

Comment: circle.getImageWidth() seems to be returning 0, any ideas why?

Comment: According to the source, it looks like the internal width and height do not get set until layout() is called. Not sure why the libgdx devs did this, but perhaps you should call circle.layout() before circle.setBounds()

Comment: the problem still persists...

Comment: I just copied the code from your original post verbatim into a brand new Libgdx project (with my own circle and greyback images) and the event happens just fine. If you aren't using a debugger, I suggest using one and putting a breakpoint in the touchDown listener to make sure that it is not being called. It could be that the println is just being redirected somwhere

Comment: i see, i appreciate it.

Comment: oh it was all cuz of a wrong import

Answer (score -1):

You need to do this :

```
stage.act();
```

This will make your Stage acting, so your Button Listener will work :)